# security error on getFile call on given directory entry in chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app

Summary : I am downloading files to chrome app sandbox file system. I have directory called 'downloads' in chrome app's sandbox file system.Following is the code sample

```
var getSubDirectory = function()
{  
subdir.getFile('demo',{create: true},function(fentry)
{
console.log(fentry);
},errohandler)
}
```

subdir is directory entry. subdir is returning properly, I am getting its output.But when i try to create file into that directory using getFile function, it throws security error.I have permission in manifest for the filesystem.write and filesyste.directory.I tried isWritableEntry() on subdir, its returning false.

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Post all of the code, including manifest.json, of a small app that illustrates the issue. Can't debug a fragment.

Comment: ^^ yes. I'd say it has to do with how you're getting <code>subdir</code>.

Comment: Just to be clear, I am trying to download files into chrome app packaged file system.Is it doable?